# How to correctly set the footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I tried many tutorials on the web, tried javascripts but nothing worked for my footer. I simply want it to stick to the bottom. If I fix it in a page where the content go below the screen the footer won't work in a page which have content within the screen size. If I fixe one the other breaks. How can I fix this?

In this page the footer is correct : http://fast-garden-6871.herokuapp.com/logs

In this page its in the midle of the screen (you have to scroll) : http://fast-garden-6871.herokuapp.com/delegates

Please help!

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: `positin: absolute; bottom: 0;`?...

Comment: @Andy Tried that... It worked for the second url but the first one broke down

Comment: Please post sample code to replicate the problem. The cs in both pages might be different and the reason for the issue could be anything… are we supposed to follow the link and debug your site..? that's not how SO works.

Comment: @EApubs Did you try to add this CSS: `.wrapper { display: block; }`

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS Code:

```
.wrapper {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your footer is the last element in your html, why don't you try...

```
body
{
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
footer
{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

or if the whole thing is wrapped in a .container div then do this instead:

```
.container {   margin-bottom:0;   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the simple code:

*html file:*

```
<div id="header"> Your header </div>
<div id="body"> Your body .. </div>
<div id="footer"> Your footer </div>
```

*css file:*

```
#header {
  background-color: blue;
}

#body {
  background-color: green;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 18px - 200px); /* calc(100vh - {{use inspect for height of header}} - {{height of footer}}*/
}

#footer {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```